# Codename One - Lock screen orientation in the Javascript port

Tags: codenameone

Assuming that my Codename One web-app is supposed to run on a mobile device, I tried to lock its orientation to portrait.

My problem is that the following build hint doesn't force the use of a web-app in portrait mode:

```
javascript.manifest.orientation=portrait
```

Am I missing something?

I also tried the following native interface, without success:

```
(function (exports) {

    var o = {};

    o.lockPortraitOrientation_ = function (callback) {
        // Screen Orientation API, https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#examples
        screen.orientation.lock('portrait');
        callback.complete();
    };

    o.isSupported_ = function (callback) {
        callback.complete(true);
    };

    exports.cool_teammate_apps_frontend_NativeUtilities = o;

})(cn1_get_native_interfaces());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the browser you tested on within the compatibility table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation)?

Assuming it is try this syntax for the native code:

```
screen.lockOrientationUniversal = screen.lockOrientation || screen.mozLockOrientation || screen.msLockOrientation;

if (screen.lockOrientationUniversal("portrait-primary")) {
  // orientation was locked
} else {
  // orientation lock failed
}
```

I'll check whether we can make our `Display` orientation calls map to these API's.

Comment: It doesn't work. I opened a RFE: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2618